# MySQL converting a tables schema while keeping the data in the new structure (best schema u ever see)

Tags: mysql, database, schema, structure

I am forking a project and want to convert one of the tables schemas to a more.. viable structure

Currently:

```
steamid | mapname | cp1 | cp2 | cp3 | cp4 | cp5 | cp6 | cp7 | cp8 | cp9 | cp10 | cp 11 | cp12 | cp13 | cp14 | cp15 | cp16 | cp17 | cp18 | cp19 | cp20 | cp21  | cp22 | cp23 | cp24 | cp25 | cp26 | cp27 | cp28 | cp29 | cp30 | cp31 | cp32 | cp33 | cp34 | cp35 | zonegroup
```

steamid is the user id, mapname is the map, the cp# columns store the players time for a specific checkpoint and the zonegroup stores which "stage" of the map

I want to change it to:

```
steamid | mapname | cp | time | zonegroup
```

Is there any realistic solution to convert this table while also keeping the data, so moving a time which was stored previously in cp1 to the new cp column which would have a value of 1,  and the new time column would contain whatever was in the old cp1 column

Thanks!

Comment: Whats problem in inserting data to your table selecting individually for each cps in the way you want?

Comment: Is zonegroup part of the primary key? Otherwise, your new model might be incorrect (e.g. not normalized).

Comment: how you want add the time columns ..  eg: using now() ??

Comment: yeah zonegroup is a primary key, so the primary keys would be steamid, mapname, cp, zonegroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transfer the data to a new table with a very long-winded `INSERT ... SELECT` query:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (steamid, mapname, cp, time, zonegroup)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT steamid, mapname, 1 AS cp, cp1 AS time, zonegroup FROM old_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT steamid, mapname, 2, cp2, zonegroup FROM old_table
    UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT steamid, mapname, 35, cp35, zonegroup FROM old_table) v
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5qzpCEEe is giving me `#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns` any ideas?

Comment: @fluffys not sure why - it works fine in this shortened [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e77e8f/2)

Comment: Are all of cp1 to cp35 the same type?

Answer (score 0):

You could use  ( a lof of ) union all

```
    select steamid, mapname, cp1 as cp , now(), zonegroup 
    from my_table  
    where cp1 is not null
    union all
    select steamid, mapname, cp2 , now(), zonegroup 
    from my_table  
    where cp2 is not null
    union all
    select steamid, mapname, cp3 , now(), zonegroup 
    from my_table  
    where cp3 is not null
    .....
    .....
    .....
    select steamid, mapname, cp34 , now(), zonegroup 
    from my_table  
    where cp34 is not null
    select steamid, mapname, cp35 , now(), zonegroup 
    from my_table  
    where cp35 is not null
```